# Executes multiples fig commands in only one supervisor program

Tags: monitoring, supervisord

I am using supervisor to monitoring my fig process. I want to configure the program command with the order of executes two fig commands in the same call. I have this configuration for redis:

```
[program:redis_fig]
command= fig up redis && fig logs redis
directory=/project
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/project/log/%(program_name)s.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

When I run it command in my shell everything works fine, but when I run it with supervisorctl, I see this error:

```
 root# supervisorctl     
    redis_fig                        FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
    supervisor>
```

I check the log file and it is the result:

```
No such service: &&
No such service: &&
```

Then I researched more deeper and I saw that `fig up` command reads all the elements after the up like an array, and of course it reads the `&&` as other service.

Then my question is: How can I configure the command attribute to run others commands    after `fig up`?

Comment: you can found the answer at this thread:

 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/24767862/418359